# Extracting the top 3 values while filtering multiple columns in dataframe (census.csv)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using pandas and trying to query the census dataset. I want to the extract the top 3 cities in every state according to the population (from largest to smallest). I'm pasting a brief snapshot of the dataset for reference purpose

[image]

The output I want is something like this

[image]

I tried to use nlargest but the problem I'm facing is that both STNAME and CTYNAME are objects. The formula I have tried is as follows:

```
def abcd(df):
    return (df.nlargest(3,['STNAME','CTYNAME','CENSUS2010POP']))
```

Another way to query it, I tried to use the groupby method:

```
df.groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME','CENSUS2010POP'].max()
```

But this formula gave me the largest value per instead of 3 largest values. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`df.groupby('STNAME').apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(3,columns='CENSUS2010POP') )`

Answer (score 0):

make CTYNAME as index as they are unique and then use groupby STNAME and take top 3 populated states by using nlargest method.

```
df = df.set_index('CTYNAME')
df.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].nlargest(3).reset_index()
```

Comment: Always add explanations to your answers to explain to the OP and others what you are solving.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
df.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP',ascending=False).groupby('STNAME',as_index=False).head(3)
```